# How do I add and mount a new hard drive in an Ubuntu Appliance running on a NUC?

Tags: mount, ubuntu-core, nextcloud

**Background:** I initially read through the [How to use the Nextcloud Ubuntu Appliance](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-nextcloud-ubuntu-appliance-with-collabora-online-on-intel-nuc#1-overview) tutorial and have successfully deployed Nextcloud on an Intel NUC. It's already configured and working through firewall with a static IP, SSL, and all that good stuff.

**Question:** How can I add a volume from a newly installed HDD in my NUC to the Nextcloud Ubuntu Appliance that's running on that NUC?

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to add storage using the Nextcloud WebUI settings?

Comment: I'm saying that I don't fully understand how to add/mount a drive in an appliance. Is it the same as in Ubuntu Server?

Comment: No: Generally, an *appliance* (meaning an application + Ubuntu Core, distributed together as a single file) has no user account for the Ubuntu Core section. That means you cannot login to the OS and use the `mount` command (or any other OS command or setting). The only settings you can access are in the application. If this is an accurate description of the problem, then please file a bug report with the Appliance author. If I have misunderstood the situation, or if you not actually using https://ubuntu.com/appliance/nextcloud and the word "appliance" has caused confusion, then please clarify.